# Как вычислить индекс группы к которой принадлежит элемент?

Tags: массивы, математика, индексация, индексы

Что-то могу сообразить как решить следующую задачу:

Есть диапазон из 360 файлов, который делится по 30 элементов на 12 частей.

Далее есть номер файла, т.е. число в диапазоне от 1 до 360. Диапазон от 1 - 30 соответствует 1-й части, диапазон от 31 - 60 соответствует 2-й части, диапазон от 61 - 90 соответствует 3-й части, ..., диапазон от 331 - 360 соответствует 12-части.

Как можно зная индекс файла (1...360) арифметически определить индекс части к которой он относится (1..12)?

Comment: Нужно просто разделить полученный индекс на 12, нацело, результат будет номером группы

Comment: @Grundy, не совсем понятно. Например, у нас есть индекс файла 59. Файл с таким индексом принадлежит второй части потому что он входит в диапазон [31; 60]. Если мы делим 59 на 12 нацело то получаем 4, а мне нужно было получить 2, потому что это вторая часть.

Comment: дели на 30 и округляй до 2х. В большую сторону.

Comment: @abg, да, действительно, надо делить на 30 (количество элементов в каждой части) при этом номер будет равен индексу начинающемуся с 0

Comment: @user2455111, возьмем для примера индекс 31, как я уже выше написал он принадлежит ко второй части. 31 / 30 = 1,03 ≈ 1, получается первая часть, хотя 31 принадлежит ко второй части.

Comment: @Grundy Нет, если 30 поделить на 30, получишь 1, и по твоим словам это вторая группа, хотя на самом деле она первая.

Comment: я же написал, округляй в большую сторону, если больше 1 индекс, то принимай его за 2

Comment: Попробуй поискать в используемом языке функцию RoundUp(). Если таковой нет - то 1+Fix().

Comment: @Akina обычно встречаю её под названием `ceil` (от *ceiling*, *потолок*).

Comment: @Akina, Добавить -1 чтобы с 0 отсчет начинался - и все ок :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, все просто. `floor` можно заменить простым целочисленным делением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю ваш вариант эквивалентен этому ⌈N/30⌉?

Comment: @abg В принципе да, но мой реализуется одной командой целочисленного деления.